# Vuejs - dynamically attaching component to a div

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building a simple blog application . In this application , I have list of blog titles and clicking on the blog title ( Link or on the div ) I want to display the blog content ( simple component which gets the data from server)  dynamically just below the blog title . But I couldn't get how to attach the component to the clicked Div . Here is the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/x8g3d5wn/6/

In this example Clicking on "Blog Title1" Div should attach the "greetings" component to this div and remove from the other Div's ( In this case from "Blog Title 3")  . Please advise or is there any other simple solution for this kind of problem .? Thank You.

```
<div id="app">    
      <div class="redColor hClass">
        Blog Title1
      </div>    
      <div class="grayColor hClass">
        Blog Title2
      </div>    
      <div class="tealColor hClass">
        Blog Title3
        <greeting></greeting>    
      </div>      
    </div>


Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: '<h1>Blog Text</h1>{{ message }}',
  data: {
    message: 'hello'
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello World! This is a Event listener test1.'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is this close to what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/x8g3d5wn/7/

Comment: Thanks for your time on checking on this one and providing solution . Wow! Yes , this is the one I am looking for .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Seems like your structure is a bit off. Though it can be used as such, vue is not a replacement for jquery. The more "natural" way would be to store blog posts in an array, and display them through the component.

```js
Vue.component('blog', {
  template: '<div :class="post.className"><h1>{{post.title}}</h1><p v-if="show">{{ post.description }}</p></div>',
  props: ['post', 'show']
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
return {
 open: -1,
  blogposts: [
    {title:"Blog Title 1", description: "Ipsum to the Lorem", className:'redColor'},
    {title:"Blog Title 2", description: "Ipsum to the Lorem", className:"grayColor"},
    {title:"Blog Title 3", description: "Ipsum to the Lorem"}
  ]
}
  },
  methods: {
   openPost(i){
 if (this.open === i) {
   this.open = null
  }
  else {
   this.open = i
  }
}
  }
});
```

```css
.redColor {
  background-color:red;
}

.grayColor {
  background-color:#999;
}

.tealColor {
  background-color:teal;
}

.hClass{
  min-height:50px;
  width:150px;
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<blog v-for="(b, i) in blogposts" :key="i" :post="b" :show="open === i" @click.native="openPost(i)"/>
</div>
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8g3d5wn/9/

Comment: Thank you for your answer . This is the first thought I have , but  1) I am not going to get the description in the first shot for performance reasons ( along with this there will be few comments and more data also )  2)  If I click on one div and if the other div already has data , we are not minimizing that div and so user will have two blogs opened with two descriptions and comments and so user has to scroll long to see the other blog titles

Comment: I was addressing the structure of data and missed the question. I updated with limit of only one blog post open at a time.

Comment: re 1) this method lends itself to async loading well, as you can update the data as it loads and the change is reactive. Additional  blog data can be added easily. If you're relying on the DOM to be there and are using vue to toggle visibility, your backend is doing most of the work. If you can set up data to be provided asynchronously, you can offload your server by getting the client to do logic. And while this may seem like a performance deficit, the user ends up getting the content quicker because there's less to transfer to the user.

Comment: Thanks again for your answers and comments on the structure . I agree with you 100% . Brilliant idea on hiding the other Div's and thanks for providing answer to my first question . I got you what you are saying and I will proceed with this approach . Seriously users will be happy with this :)